# How to define variables and echo them in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I've added this code into a Smarty template file:

```
$totalearnings = {$pendingcommissions|replace:' USD':''|replace:'$':''} + {$balance|replace:' USD':''|replace:'$':''} + {$withdrawn|replace:' USD':''|replace:'$':''};
echo $totalearnings;
```

This is how it's displaying on the page:

```
$totalearnings = 0.00 + 1010.00 + 2000.00;
echo $totalearnings;
```

What exactly do I need to change to make this code work?  `$totalearnings` should be adding the numbers instead of just displaying the equation on the page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `{assign var="name" value="Bob"}`

```
{assign var="p" value=$pendingcommissions|replace:' USD':''|replace:'$':'' }

{assign var="b" value=$balance|replace:' USD':''|replace:'$':'' }

{assign var="w" value=$withdrawn|replace:' USD':''|replace:'$':'' }

{assign var="totalearnings" value=0}

{assign var="totalearnings" value=$totalearnings+$p+$b+$w}

{$totalearnings}
```

[{assign}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl)

Comment: I tried that but it came out to `0.00`.  I think the problem is with `{assign var="totalearnings" value=$p+ $b+ $w}` because the other variables are working from your code...

Comment: Actually I just figured it out.  It looks like you can't have spaces between the plus signs and the variables.